# Resource exception in DLL

Tags: c#, winforms, dll

I have a Windows Forms Application that compiles and runs perfectly.

I have converted this to a DLL by creating a new DLL project and linking the existing forms and classes to the new project.

The DLL project compiles, but gets stuck at runtime when it gets to anything got to do with a resource, like the form's icon or imagelist.

It throws an error:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.Resources.MissingManifestResourceException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
```

on the following line of code:

```
this.LargeImageList.ImageStream = ((System.Windows.Forms.ImageListStreamer)(resources.GetObject("LargeImageList.ImageStream")));
```

Do I have to change how the icons and images are stored for the DLL to work correctly?

Comment: The Designer.cs file got out of sync with the .resx file for the form.  That's not unthinkable when you "convert" stuff, you left no breadcrumbs.  Re-entering the image list would be a workaround.

Comment: This is happening with form's icon too. Interestingly, when I tried to re-add the icon from the DLL project using the IDE, it added a new `InitializeComponent()` method in `BaseForm.cs` (BaseForm being the form name) in addition to the existing method in `BaseForm.Designer.cs`. The compiler of course flagged the conflict and I had to remove it.

Answer (score 0):

As you changed the name of the assembly / type of the application,  you need to fix the way how you handled your resources and how the resourcess were been referred.

You have to access the specific assembly and you can read resources on it.

```
Stream stream = yourAssembly.GetManifestResourceStream(myResourceName);
```

Answer (score 0):

When I copied all the linked files to the project folder of the new DLL project and then added them to the project instead of linking them to files in the original project folder, it worked.